# In LWC, an external script is loaded with an attribute "locker-data-src" instead of just src

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to load an external script, the script looks loaded properly. however, can't access the object & it's methods in that script. The script is loaded with attribute "locker-data-src" & not with a "src". Does that make any difference?

Comment: See if this answer helps you : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263719/how-to-load-and-use-external-library
Can you share your code?

Comment: Yes, that helps! But I am able to load the script, the problem is with the attribute "locker-data-src". How can I get rid of it & just have the src attribute?

Answer (score 0):

[Lightning Locker](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm) takes control of the `src` attribute on the `HTMLScriptElement` tag to load and evaluate the script in the sandbox. The original `src` attribute is reflected to the `locker-data-src` attribute.

It's not possible to set directly the `src` attribute because it would mean that the loaded script would execute outside the sandbox.